# Android: setLastModified issue

Tags: android, file

The `setLastModified` method doesn't seem to change the file last modification time: can someone explain me why? Am I doing something wrong or it's just my device?
[image]Here in this picture I print in logcat the last modification value before and after calling the `setLastModified` method on my file.

Comment: What is the boolean return value?

Comment: it's false.. im I doing something wrong then ?

Comment: Can you provide the value you are attempting to change it to? and where is this file located?
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setLastModified(long)

Comment: The value is obtained from a "file.lastModified" call previously done. Basically what i'm trying to do is modify the value of a text file keeping it's original "LastModified" value. I am doing so receiving the "LastModified" value from the file, editing and saving the file, than reset the "LastModified" value as it was originally.

Comment: is the file in /sdcard?

Comment: Not in sdcard but it's in the external storage

Comment: I'm facing this issue, and I'm told the 'setLastModified(long)' is unreliable on Android.